# Querying BigQuery cached temp tables gives different results everytime

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a very large dataset (approx 20TB) in BigQuery. The problem is I have to get the data in an ordered way and to do that I have to use the ORDER BY clause. Now when I am using order by clause, the data are getting returned but when I add LIMIT and OFFSET to it, it's exceeding the resource limit. Now to counter that I came up with a way to use the temp cache table that is created every time I run a query in it.
So essentially I run an ORDER BY query to sort the data which is getting saved in the temp table and then I am using that temp table to get a small part of the data using LIMIT and OFFSET. But sometimes the temp table is giving random results and the results are not ordered as it should be.
I read in the BigQuery doc multiple time that
`using them as inputs for dependent jobs is strongly discouraged`
but I never found the reason for that. Also, the randomization of the data is not happening in all the case, but in some case. Am I missing something here?

If there is a better alternative to getting the sorted data other than using temp cache table, that is also welcomed.

Note: I have tried creating a temp table on my own to store the ordered data, but that is also throwing `resource exceeded error`